# Bootstrap select get the selected option value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select

I need to get the selected option value for the Bootstrap select picker, as Bootstrap re-render the select to be button & UL. I got the text as following:

```
$( document.body ).on( 'click', '#add_course .dropdown-menu li', function( event ) {

    var $target = $( event.currentTarget );

    $target
        .closest( '.btn-group' )
        .find( 'data-value' )
        .text( $target.text() )
        .end()
        .children( '.dropdown-toggle' )
        .dropdown( 'toggle' );

    alert($target.text() );

    return false;
});
```

Can someone help?